# Как в SQL запросе вывести ещё одно поле со своим условием

Tags: sql

День добрый! Есть такая структура:

```
PeopleID | Name   | Father | Mother
-----------------------------------
1        | Vasia  | null   | null
2        | Sveta  | 4      | 3
3        | Lena   | null   | null
4        | Andrey | null   | null
5        | Kostik | 1      | null
6        | Olga   | 4      | 3
```

Т.е. у Андрея 2 ребенка Света и Ольга, у Васи 1 - Костик.

Мне нужно вывести запросом отца у которого больше всего детей.
Я научился находить ИД отца, который чаще всего встречается в столбце Father.
Но нужно ещё вывести Name который соответствует этому отцу. Т.е. как-то так сделать, примерно,  ещё один вывод с условием "Name FROM Family WHERE PeopleID=COUNT(Father)"

```
SELECT Father, COUNT(Father) AS value_occurrence 
    FROM     FAMILY
        WHERE Father IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Father
    ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
    LIMIT    1;
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: Так просто еще Name через запятую в select добавьте

Comment: Если добавить Name в селект, то он выводит последнюю строку из таблицы, где встречается  этот ИД.

Comment: Используйте две копии таблицы. По первой считайте, из второй берите имя.

Comment: `SELECT F2.NAME, F1.Father, COUNT(F1.Father) AS value_occurrence FROM FAMILY F1 
JOIN FAMILY F2 on F1.Father = F2.PeopleID 
GROUP BY F1.Father, F2.NAME 
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC 
LIMIT    1;` Попробуйте так.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое — подзапрос или соединение. Вариант с соединением вам уже дали в комментариях. Вариант с подзапросом будет как-то так:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM Value_Occurrence
 WHERE PeopleID = (
  SELECT Father
    FROM Value_Occurrence
   WHERE Father IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY Father
   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 1
);
```

Если вам надо вывести *всех* отцов с максимальным числом детей, запрос становится несколько сложнее:

```sql
WITH FatherCounts AS (
  SELECT Father
       , COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM Value_Occurrence
   WHERE Father IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY Father
),
FatherRanks AS (
  SELECT Father
       , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Count DESC) AS Rank
    FROM FatherCounts
)
SELECT Value_Occurrence.*
  FROM Value_Occurrence
  JOIN FatherRanks
    ON PeopleID = FatherRanks.Father
 WHERE Rank = 1;
```

Опять же, вариант без `JOIN`ов:

```sql
-- …
SELECT *
  FROM Value_Occurrence
 WHERE PeopleID IN (
  SELECT Father
    FROM FatherRanks
   WHERE Rank = 1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1 используем inner join что бы выбрать только соединенные строки исключая нулевые записи:

```
SELECT F2.NAME, F1.Father, COUNT(F1.Father) AS value_occurrence 
FROM FAMILY F1 
JOIN FAMILY F2 on F1.Father = F2.PeopleID 
GROUP BY F1.Father, F2.NAME 
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Вариант 2 делаем select из двух таблиц где столбец father равен столбцу peopleID:

```
SELECT F2.NAME, F1.Father, COUNT(F1.Father) AS value_occurrence 
FROM FAMILY F1, FAMILY F2 where F1.Father = F2.PeopleID 
GROUP BY F1.Father, F2.NAME 
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC LIMIT 1;
```

---

**Требуется проверка, в настоящий момент нет под рукой БД.**